# which is better setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) or GraphicsDevice device?

Tags: java, screen-resolution

I am planning on making a full screen application in Java. I have come across 2 sets of ways to make the application full screen.

```
1. frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)
2. GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[0];
    device.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
```

Both of these do the same that is make the frame full screen. What I would like to know which of these are better?
If I was to use this application on different screen resolution would they behave the same .Example projectors etc

Comment: Could you edit your title to reflect your question please

Answer (score 1):

Approach `2.` is preferred.  The best thing to do is check if fullscreen mode is available:

```
if (device.isFullScreenSupported()) {
    device.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
} else {
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
}
```

Maximizing a frame is the equivalent of double-clicking the title bar.  It will not fill the parts of the screen used by the desktop's taskbar or other reserved areas, and its decorations (title bar, border, close/minimize/maximize buttons) will still be visible, which probably is not what you want.

Comment: but if I was to `setUndecorated(true)` of the frame then it would be full screen, without the taskbar etc.

Comment: Whenever I maximize an undecorated frame, the taskbar is still shown.